# How to display partially selected list items in UI5?

Tags: checkbox, sapui5, sap-fiori

Is there a way that I could partially select a list item with `sap.m.ListBase` mode set as `MultiSelect`?

Something like this for some of the entries in the list:
https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.CheckBox/sample/sap.m.sample.CheckBoxTriState

[image: SAPUI5 checkbox in tri-state]

In the official UI5 [API reference for `sap.m.Checkbox`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.CheckBox#methods/setPartiallySelected), there's the property `partiallySelected`. But for the `sap.m.ListBase`, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who faces this problem, I found a solution,

So earlier I was relying on the checkboxes provided by the list's MultiSelect mode and then displaying the items as StandardListItem but I later replaced it with CustomListItem and in it, added my own checkboxes, in which I could set the partially selected property.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the tri-state makes much sense in combination of `sap.m.ListBase` and `mode="MultiSelect"`. According to the [SAP Fiori Design Guideline checkbox sections regarding "Tri-State"](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/checkbox/#tristate):

> ### Usage
>
> [...]
>
> You want to group **multiple suboptions under a parent option**, and require an intermediate selection state (tri-state). The tri-state indicates that some (but not all) **suboptions** are selected.
>
> [...]
>
> The main purpose of this state is to represent the mixed selection states of dependent input fields. If some (but not all) of the dependent fields are selected, the checkbox shows a partially selected state. This is only a visual state and can’t be achieved by a direct user interaction.

Unless the list control is of type `sap.m.Tree`, displaying tri-state checkboxes in `sap.m.ListItemBase` without any suboptions deviates from common UX patterns and thus might be confusing for end users. I'd suggest reviewing SAP Fiori Design Guidelines (or other design guidelines in case of freestyle) and re-evaluating whether checkbox is really the correct UI element for the intended interaction design.